# Cannot save Entity with related itself

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

Let say I have a situation like this.

Here is my table (with ParentID column contains value of LocationID):

Example:

```
            LocationID        LocationCode        ParentID
Row 1           1              Code_Parent          NULL
Row 2           2              Code_Child            1 //ID of row 1
```

Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location]
(
    [LocationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [LocationCode] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [LocationName] [nvarchar](125) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Location_LocationID] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LocationID] ASC)
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Location_Location_ParentID] 
    FOREIGN KEY([ParentID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([LocationID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Location] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Location_Location_ParentID]
GO
```

Entity Framework 6.0:

EF was generated from PowerTool, and here are the class:

```
public LocationMap()
{
    // Primary Key
    this.HasKey(t => t.LocationID);

    // Properties
    this.Property(t => t.LocationCode)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(20);

    this.Property(t => t.LocationName)
                .HasMaxLength(125);

    // Table & Column Mappings
    this.ToTable("Location");
    this.Property(t => t.LocationID).HasColumnName("LocationID");
    this.Property(t => t.ParentID).HasColumnName("ParentID");
    this.Property(t => t.LocationCode).HasColumnName("LocationCode");
    this.Property(t => t.LocationName).HasColumnName("LocationName");

    // Relationships
    this.HasOptional(t => t.Location2)
                .WithMany(t => t.Location1)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.ParentID);
}
```

Implementation:

- `MD_Location1` is list of children
- `MD_Location2` is parent location

Code:

```
IUnitOfWorkAsync _unitOfWorkAsync = new UnitOfWork(dataContext); //it worked

// 1. add parent location
MD_Location locParent = new MD_Location()
        {
            ParentID = null,
            LocationName = "Parent 1",
            ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
        };

// 2. add 2 child locations
MD_Location locChild1 = new MD_Location()
        {
            ParentID = locParent.LocationID,     // is code right?
            LocationName = "Child 1",
            ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
        };

locChild1.MD_Location2 = locParent;      // I tried but it does not work
locParent.MD_Location1.Add(locChild1);   // I also tried but it not work either

MD_Location locChild2 = new MD_Location()
        {
            ParentID = locParent.LocationID,   // is code right?
            LocationName = "Child 2",
            ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
        };

locChild2.MD_Location2 = locParent;     // I tried but it does not work
locParent.MD_Location1.Add(locChild2);  // I also tried but it not work either

_unitOfWorkAsync.Repository<MD_Location>().Insert(location);
_unitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges();
```

But an error occurs:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Location' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

How could I solve this problem?

Please advise.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you have execute SaveChanges() on locParent object first before assigning its Id to locChild1 ParentID field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a reduced working solution without any noise:

Model definition:

```
public class Model1 : DbContext
{
    public Model1()
        : base( "name=Model1" )
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
    {
        base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );

        var location = modelBuilder.Entity<Location>();

        // location.ToTable( nameof( Location ) );
        location.HasKey( e => e.Id );
        location.Property( e => e.Code )
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength( 20 );
        location.Property( e => e.Name )
            .HasMaxLength( 125 );
        location.HasOptional( e => e.Parent )
            .WithMany( e => e.Children )
            .HasForeignKey( e => e.ParentId )
            .WillCascadeOnDelete( false );
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Use case

```
using ( var db = new Model1() )
{
    var parent_location = new Location
    {
        Code = "Code_Parent",
    };

    var child_location = new Location
    {
        Code = "Code_Child",
        Parent = parent_location,
    };

    db.Locations.Add( child_location );
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

The main  difference is, that I attach the instance to a navigation property (`Parent = parent_location`) and EF will do the rest and also take care of the parent location I did not explicit add to the locations collection.

Comment: hi Sir Rufo,
If we insert from child_location, how about the case: 1 parent has more than one child?
Still we use as this:    db.Locations.Add( child_location1 ); db.Locations.Add( child_location2 );

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

when you assign parrentId from locParent.LocationID before saving that object to the database and if you have identity enabled on that column then `LocationId` Property will hold value 0 and EF has no Idea that ParentId needs to attach from auto generated Id of locParent object.

```
    MD_Location locChild2 = new MD_Location()
    {
        //ParentID = locParent.LocationID, //is not correct
        LocationName = "Child 2",
        ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
    };
```

Instead you should use navigation property so that EF can understand that locParent object needs to be first saved and its autogenerated Id needs to be saved in locChild2's ParentId column.

```
    MD_Location locChild2 = new MD_Location()
    {
        MD_Location2 = locParent,
        LocationName = "Child 2",
        ObjectState = ObjectState.Added
    };
```

Comment: hi Jenish Rabdiya, I tried as your sample (I wrote in the question: locChild1.MD_Location2 = locParent;), and it did not work.